# Programmatically retrieve the site URL from inside an Azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure websites have a default "site URL" provided by Azure, something like mysite.azurewebsites.net. Is it possible to get this URL from inside the website itself (i.e. from the ASP.NET application)?

There are several properties in the Environment and HttpRuntime class that contain the name of the website (e.g. "mysite") so that is easily accessible. Things are getting complicated when not the default but e.g. the staging slot of the site is accessed (that has the site URL like mysite-staging.azurewebsites.net).

So I was just wondering whether there is a straightforward way of getting this site URL directly. If not, then using one of the mentioned classes to get the site name and then somehow detecting the site slot (that could e.g. be set through a configuration value from the Azure portal) would be the solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Edit (2/4/16):** You can get the `URL` from the appSetting/EnvironmentVariable `websiteUrl`. This will also give you the custom hostname if you have one setup.

There are few of ways you can do that.

### 1. From the `HOSTNAME` header

This is valid **only** if the request is hitting the site using `<SiteName>.azurewebsites.net`. Then you can just look at the `HOSTNAME` header for the `<SiteName>.azurewebsites.net`

```
var hostName = Request.Headers["HOSTNAME"].ToString()
```

### 2. From the `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME` Environment Variable

This just gives you the `<SiteName>` part so you will have to append the `.azurewebsites.net` part

```
var hostName = string.Format("http://{0}.azurewebsites.net", Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%"));
```

### 3. From `bindingInformation` in `applicationHost.config` using `MWA`

you can use the code [here to read the IIS config file `applicationHost.config`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator.aspx) 
and then read the `bindingInformation` property on your site. Your function might look a bit different, something like this

```
private static string GetBindings()
{
    // Get the Site name 
    string siteName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;

    // Get the sites section from the AppPool.config
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection sitesSection =
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(null, null,
            "system.applicationHost/sites");

    foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement site in sitesSection.GetCollection())
    {
        // Find the right Site
        if (String.Equals((string) site["name"], siteName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {

            // For each binding see if they are http based and return the port and protocol
            foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement binding in site.GetCollection("bindings")
                )
            {
                var bindingInfo = (string) binding["bindingInformation"];
                if (bindingInfo.IndexOf(".azurewebsites.net", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                {
                    return bindingInfo.Split(':')[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Personally, I would use number 2

Comment: I forgot to tell why I'm asking this question: this site doesn't use the default host name but a custom domain, so that's why I haven't gone with number 1 without hesitation. So number 2 it will be. Thank you for your exceptionally detailed answer! Now I also know about WAWS environment variables existing.

Comment: You are welcome. Also check the scm endpoint `https://<yourSiteName>.scm.azurewebsites.net` basically going over `https` and adding `.scm` after the name. There is an Environment tab that lists all the different environment variables WAWS give you. there are also a bunch of useful tools there. You can read more about accessing project kudu here https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service

Comment: Actually number 2 returns the default live site URL, even from the staging slot. However I discovered that apparently WAWS adds a HTTP header called DISGUISED_HOST, that includes the correct site URL, even on the staging slot (e.g. mysite-staging.azurewebsites.net).

Comment: oh, you are correct. the site name is the same between the staging and production slot. Keep in mind that `DISGUISED_HOST` will be the hostname the user hits the site on. Actually from the point of view of the application `DISGUISED_HOST` and `HOST` should be the same, the reason `DISGUISED_HOST` exist has to do with the lower level implementation of traffic routing between slots. We are looking into adding an environment variable that would just be your `.azurewebsites.net` domain to help address this particular scenario

Comment: OK, thanks, looking forward to it then. Actually you're right, this only works for me because the site is behind a reverse proxy, thus it's always being hit through the azurewebsites.net subdomain. However there is a module to re-write the host header to the original one, that's why I see a different value in the HOST and DISGUISED_HOST header (and can use the latter for my purpose).

Comment: @ahmelsayed can you please provide the code for retriving the appSetting/EnvironmentVariable 'websiteUrl' i can no see the WebsiteUrl variable in the list of environment variable on the server in azure

Comment: How can get figure out the slot name on startup, when there is not request object?

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")`.

This will return full URL (`"http://{your-site-name}.azurewebsites.net"`), no string manipulations required.

To see a full list of properties available in environment variables just type `Get-ChildItem Env:` in SCM PowerShell debug console.

Comment: This is not true, it does not include the "http(s)://", but indeed the ".azurewebsites.net"