# how to get hostname in webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, startup

I have tried following code

```
  string host = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

inside Starup.cs and hosted on Azure cloud inside websites.
but it returns `127.0.0.1` why not `mysite.azurewebsites.net`

In mvc application I use this code inside `HomeController.cs` it return correct azure website name.

Comment: Here's your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23207697/881798

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically retrieve the site URL from inside an Azure website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207147/programmatically-retrieve-the-site-url-from-inside-an-azure-website)