# Images are not displayed after publishing the bot with continuous deployment

Tags: github, continuous-integration, botframework, azure-web-app-service, wwwroot

I have developed a bot using Bot Framework. It shows images when I run it locally on the Bot Framework Emulator. But after publishing it on Azure by creating a private GitHub repository, none of the images are displayed. I'm using Direct-Line API 3.0. What could be the reason?

Like, here's the tree-view of my project. The images folder resides in Content Root.

[image: Project Tree View]

I'm using the following static method to retrieve an image path.

```
public static string CreateImagePath(string filename)
    {
        return Path.Combine(TempData.HostingEnvironment?.ContentRootPath, "images", $"{filename}");
    }
```

And then converting it into a Uri, and assigning it to an Adaptive Card's image. Here's the code snippet.

```
(AdaptiveCardFactory.CreateAdaptiveElement(card, "image") as AdaptiveImage).Url =
            new Uri(PathFactory.CreateImagePath("welcome_card_image.png"));
```

CreateAdaptiveElement is defined as:

```
public static AdaptiveElement CreateAdaptiveElement(AdaptiveCard card, string adaptiveElementId)
    {
        return card.Body.Find(ae => ae.Id == adaptiveElementId);
    }
```

This is the Uri that is returned when I run the bot locally. it works fine.

```
file:///C:/Users/Husai/source/repos/PanjaSahibBot/images/welcome_card_image.png
```

Here's what is returned after publishing.

```
file:///D:/home/site/wwwroot/images/welcome_card_image.png
```

And, it's not working.

Here's the latest command log.

```
    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\GurdwaraBot.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file D:\home\site\repository\obj\GurdwaraBot.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file D:\home\site\repository\obj\GurdwaraBot.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 5.02 sec for D:\home\site\repository\GurdwaraBot.csproj.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 1.41 sec for D:\home\site\repository\GurdwaraBot.csproj.
  GurdwaraBot -> D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\GurdwaraBot.dll
  GurdwaraBot -> D:\local\Temp\8d6da8df6d390f3\
Creating app_offline.htm
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\local\Temp\8d6da8df6d390f3' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'GurdwaraBot.deps.json'
Copying file: 'GurdwaraBot.dll'
Copying file: 'GurdwaraBot.pdb'
Copying file: 'GurdwaraBot.runtimeconfig.json'
Copying file: 'images\01d.png'
Copying file: 'images\01n.png'
Copying file: 'images\02d.png'
Copying file: 'images\02n.png'
Copying file: 'images\03d.png'
Copying file: 'images\03n.png'
Copying file: 'images\04d.png'
Copying file: 'images\04n.png'
Copying file: 'images\09d.png'
Copying file: 'images\09n.png'
Copying file: 'images\1.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\10.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\10d.png'
Copying file: 'images\10n.png'
Copying file: 'images\11d.png'
Copying file: 'images\11n.png'
Copying file: 'images\13d.png'
Copying file: 'images\13n.png'
Copying file: 'images\2.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\3.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\4.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\5.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\50d.png'
Copying file: 'images\50n.png'
Copying file: 'images\6.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\7.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\8.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\9.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\bill.png'
Copying file: 'images\feedback.png'
Copying file: 'images\Festivals.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_bandi_chhor_divas.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_gurpurab.jpeg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_hola_mohalla.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_maghi.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_martyrdom_of_guru_arjan.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_parkash_utsav_dasveh_patshah.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\festivals_vaisakhi.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\menu_card_image.png'
Copying file: 'images\panja_thumbnail_1.png'
Copying file: 'images\panja_thumbnail_2.png'
Copying file: 'images\panja_thumbnail_3.png'
Copying file: 'images\pof_guest_hotel.jpg'
Copying file: 'images\question.png'
Omitting next output lines...
Finished successfully.
```

This is what I am expecting.
[Locally executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUxcz.png)
And, this is what I'm getting via DirectLine!!
[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Lgs.png)

Here's the content of my welcome_card.json

```
    {
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Image",
      "id": "image",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
      "style": "Person",
      "url": "",
      "size": "Medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "color": "Accent",
      "text": "Welcome to Gurdwara Bot",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
      "text": "Hi there! I'm the Sri Panja Sahib's support bot. What can I help you with today? Just so you know, you can enter **MENU** anytime you want to go back to the options below, or just go ahead type your query.",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Get an Overview",
      "data": {
        "dataId": "overview"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Ask a Question",
      "data": {
        "dataId": "question"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Book a Room",
      "data": {
        "dataId": "room"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Give a Feedback",
      "data": {
        "dataId": "feedback"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.0",
  "speak": "Hi there! I'm the Sri Panja Sahib's support bot. What can I help you with today? Just so you know, you can enter **MENU** anytime you want to go back to the options below, or just go ahead type your query."
}
```

I've defined AdaptiveCardFactory to manipulate with cards.

```
public class AdaptiveCardFactory
{
    public static AdaptiveCard CreateAdaptiveCard(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var adaptiveCardJson = File.ReadAllText(path);
            AdaptiveCardParseResult result = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(adaptiveCardJson);
             return result.Card;
        }
        catch (AdaptiveSerializationException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(AdaptiveCard card)
    {
        return new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = card,
        };
    }

    public static AdaptiveElement CreateAdaptiveElement(AdaptiveCard card, string adaptiveElementId)
    {
        return card.Body.Find(ae => ae.Id == adaptiveElementId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the images were published? Are you sure about the path when it is published? You can use Kudu to check if the files are deployed on your Web App

Comment: @NicolasR, yes the images are published, and I'm sure about the path. Also, all images are deployed on my Web App.

Comment: Can you add more details about your implementation (on how you use this Uri that you create)?

Comment: @NicolasR yeah sure!!

Comment: @NicolasR can it be the issue of slashes? Check out the log, it's "images\", but in the returned uri, it's "images/".

Comment: I have an other idea in mind, I got to check with a quick demo. By that time, can you directly check the files directly on the server using Kudu  (https://YOUR_BOT_SITE.scm.azurewebsites.net > Debug Console > CMD)?

Comment: Yes, the files are in the correct directory. I just checked through the link you sent me.  Here: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\images".

Comment: Can you also share what's behind your `AdaptiveCardFactory.CreateAdaptiveElement` call please?

Comment: @NicolasR Yes, sure!! :)

Comment: And your card sample maybe... so that I can reproduce the display on my side ;-)

Comment: So @NicolasR, I've added my card's JSON.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Will post a reply soon

Comment: @NicolasR Thank you so much! :) I've also shared ApdaptiveCardFactory class so you may know how I'm de-serializing the cards.

Comment: In fact it should have been obvious in my mind from the beginning! See my reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

You must provide public URLs for items displayed in AdaptiveCards, not local ones. It is working in local with the emulator because... you are in local, and the emulator has access to your local files, so it can understand files with local location (`C:\...` or `D:\...` files).

So change your path so that it uses your sub-domain: you can do it here, for example by using a configuration variable instead of `TempData.HostingEnvironment?.ContentRootPath`

```
public static string CreateImagePath(string filename)
{
    return Path.Combine(TempData.HostingEnvironment?.ContentRootPath, "images", $"{filename}");
}
```

**Details:**

`AdaptiveCard` item is passed as an attachment in the bot message, everything that is inside is rendered by the client (channel), so it can only render things that are "visible" from the outside.

See my demo here: I used a Card with an ImageSet of 2 images: one with an URL over the web, the other with an URL build like yours.

Local: both images are OK.
[image]

Published: only 1st image is displayed
[image: Published]

If you look at the Inspector on the right-side, it becomes obvious that you must change the way you build your image Url.

You can also have a look to your deployed webchat by right-clicking the zone where the image should be, and you will find a link with a `D:\...` path

**Code Fix**

1st, move your `images` folder inside `wwwroot` folder of your projet. Then you can do the following:

```
public string CreateImagePath(string filename)
{
    if (_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        return Path.Combine(TempData.HostingEnvironment?.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot", "images", $"{filename}");
    }
    else
    {
        var targetUri = new Uri(new Uri($"https://{Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%")}.azurewebsites.net"), Path.Combine("images", $"{filename}"));
        return targetUri.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've used many images that are on the web, and they are being displayed in the cards like yours, even after publishing. But most of the images that I populate my cards with are in "images" folder. I want to render my cards with those images. Isn't there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: As you copy them on publish, they are available! You just have to use « https://yourBot.azurewebsites.net/images/filename.jpg » instead

Comment: You can do it by several ways, see for example this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207147/programmatically-retrieve-the-site-url-from-inside-an-azure-website

Comment: I added a code conclusion to help you do the switch between local and deployed uri

Comment: Wow! It worked like a magic... Thank you so much Nicolas Robert. 